# Like XMind but with directed acyclic graph?

Tags: mind-mapping

Are there any mind-mapping tools, like [XMind](http://www.xmind.net/), but which basic structure not tree, but [directed acyclic graph (DAG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)?

I don't know why do they do trees everywhere like tree maniacs! :)

Tree is always insufficient structure for mind mapping!

I know that many tools allow drawing arrows between nodes like that XMind or Visio. But I need DAG structure be essential and constraint, allowing collapsing ets...

Comment: Fully agree! Have you found anything yet?

Answer (score 2):

The best I've found so far is yEd, available here:
https://www.yworks.com/products/yed

The default settings for the editor behavior are quite uncommon, but after fiddling with the (quite extensive) preferences, I really quite like it! It also includes nice layout algorithms that place nodes of a directed acyclic graph in a way that minimizes intersections.

Comment: It is impossible to paste images into yEd